# Query doesn't show some records while using select with concat on 2 columns

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

My table

```
id_street | main_name | feature | name | gus_compatible |
----------+-----------+---------+------+----------------+
38454     | woods     | alley   |      | t              |
----------+-----------+---------+------+----------------+
38455     | hills     |         |      | t              |
```

My query

```
SELECT id_street, feature || ' ' || main_name AS street FROM streets ORDER BY main_name DESC
```

In my data output I will see the street `alley woods`, but there will be no `hills`. Why is it happening?

Comment: What is the stored value of feature for hills? An empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any concatenation of a NULL value in postgresql will return NULL.  This is by design.  You'll need to convert the NULL value to an empty string using COALESCE(feature,'') so that no NULL values are used in the concatenation.